# complex SQLite insert for recipe database

Tags: sqlite

I normally have a monolithic table for recipes so it's easy to insert it into the database in one statement as below:

```
INSERT INTO Recipes(Version, Owner, Title, Categories, Serves, Source,
                    Ingredients, Instructions, PictureName, LastUpdate,
                    Favourite, Deleted)
    VALUES('" + Version$ + "','" + Owner$ + "','" + Title$ + "','" +
           Categories$ + "','" + Serve$ + "','" + Source$ + "','" +
           Ingredient$ + "','" + InStruction$ + "','" + PictureName$  +
           "','" + LaStUpdate + "','" + Favourite$ + "','" + "0"
```

But, I want to 'normalise' my database as below to be more flexible, save space, redundancies etc. Rather than normalising an existing database, I will start from scratch using the same form to gather the data (Ingredients, instructions and categories are lists) but I don't know how to make a complex/compound insert query to take care of all the relationships for the linked tables etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am new at this 'normalisation' strategy.

```
  recipes table                recipe_id
                               recipe_name
                               recipe_version
                               recipe_owner
                               recipe_author
                               recipe_source
                               recipe_copyright
                               recipe_lastupdate
                               recipe_favourite
                               recipe_deleted
                               recipe_description
                               recipe_notes
                               recipe_servings
                               recipe_peparationtime
                               recipe_cookingtime
                               recipe_totaltime

  ingredients table            ingredient_id
                               ingredient_name
                               ingredient_price

  recipe_ingredients table     recipe_id
                               ingredient_id
                               ingredient_amount

  recipe_instructions table    recipe_id
                               recipe_step
                               step_description

  category table               category_id
                               category_name

  recipe_category table        recipe_id
                               category_id

  picture table                picture_id
                               picture_name
                               picture_url

  recipe_pictures table        recipe_id
                               picture_id
```

Comment: Search for `database normalization`

Comment: Listen. I tried to help you, *somehow*. It's a **broad** answer. You better search and find an **exhaustive** `lesson/tutorial`, which is **not appropriate**, here.